# Fetch data from fbsdk react native

Tags: android, facebook, react-native, react-native-fbsdk

Hi I have implemented the Facebook login in my react native app. I have not used the standard button that comes with sdk. Everything work fine login is successful. But now I don't know how to extract data from Facebook user profile i.e name, email.

Below is my code

```
_fbAuth() {
        LoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(['public_profile']).then(function (result) {
            if (result.isCancelled) {
                console.log('Login was Cancelled');
            } else {

                        const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;

                //
              console.log('Login Successful' + result.grantedPermissions.toString());



            }
        }, function (error) {
            console.log('An error has occured' + error);
        })
    }
```

code for button

```
<TouchableHighlight onPress={() => { this._fbAuth() }}>
                            <Image source={require('../images/facebook-logo.png')} style={styles.facebook}></Image>
                        </TouchableHighlight>
```

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/overview
I don't know what data you need. but you will get the basic permissions like email address access, date of birth, name etc. Facebook does not allow all the user data to be fetched.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use **AccessToken** function along with the **LoginManager** to get the token when login is successful. After receiving the token, we can use this token to retrieve data of logged-in user using graph api of facebook.

Consider the code below:

```js
import { LoginManager, AccessToken } from 'react-native-fbsdk'; 

async _fbAuth() {
    let { isCancelled } = await LoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(['public_profile','user_posts']);

    if ( !isCancelled ) {
        let data = await AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
        let token = data.accessToken.toString();
        await afterLoginComplete(token);
    }
    else {
        console.log('Login incomplete');
    }

}

const afterLoginComplete = async (token) => {
    const response = await fetch(
        `https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id,name,first_name,last_name,gender,picture,cover&access_token=${token}`);
    let result = await response.json();

    // use this result as per the requirement
};
```

You can learn how to use facebook graph API from [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api)

Answer (score 1):

```
import {AccessToken,LoginManager} from 'react-native-fbsdk';

  fbAuth() {
    var current =  this;
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
      LoginManager.setLoginBehavior('web');
        LoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(['public_profile','email']).then(
      function (result) {
        if (result.isCancelled) {
          console.log('Login was cancelled');
        } 


         else {
          //var accessToken  = null;

          AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().then(
            (data) => {
              console.log(data.accessToken.toString())
             const{accessToken}   = data

  // with the help of access token you can get details for fb login

            console.log('accessToken: ' + accessToken);
             fetch('https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/me?fields=email,name,friends&access_token=' +accessToken)
             .then((response) => response.json())
             .then((json) => {
               console.log('jsonn: ' + json);
               console.log('Login name: ' + json.name);
               console.log('Login id: ' + json.id);
               console.log('Login email: ' + json.email);
               var nsn = json.name
               console.log('Login email state: ' +nsn);   
               var idfb = json.id
               console.log('Login email state: ' +idfb);  
               var idemail = json.email
               console.log('Login email state: ' +idemail);  

             })
             .catch(() => {
               reject('ERROR GETTING DATA FROM FACEBOOK')
             })

            })

        }
      },
      function (error) {
        console.log('Login failed with error: ' + error);
      }
    );
  }
```